# Can create user but then cannot alter it?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to create a user and then alter it in SQL Server. So far I have:

```
CREATE LOGIN bob1 WITH PASSWORD = '!abcd1234' 
GO

ALTER USER bob1 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
GO
```

The first statement works, but then for the second I get:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 
> Cannot alter the user 'bob1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

What does that mean exactly? And why would I be able to create a user and then not be able to modify it?

---

It seems I'm mixing up `LOGIN` and `USER`. What is the difference between these two items?

Comment: In Azure, Login is not a user,  it's used to login the Azure SQL database, you need create the user for login: `CREATE USER BOB1 FOR LOGIN bob1`, then run `ALTER USER bob1 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;`. But it's not necessary, the default schema is `dbo`, we could not specify it.

Comment: Create login to log in the Server/database, then mapping the user to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure, Login is not a user, it's used to login the Azure SQL database, you need create the user for login: `CREATE USER BOB1 FOR LOGIN bob1`, then run A`LTER USER bob1 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo`;. But it's not necessary, the default schema is dbo, we could not specify it.

Create login to log in the Server/database, then mapping the user to login.

After that you need alter the user enough permission/role to access the database, for example:

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER 'bob1'
```

Please ref here: [Authorize database access to SQL Database, SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage)

Comment: What's the difference between `ALTER ROLE` and using a `GRANT` to give someone permissions?

Comment: @David542 `ALTER ROLE` is grant database role to user. GRANT to grant some permissions.In usually,  [ALTER ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  have more permission than [GRANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).